# Zap: How to export Fuzzer results/report with the Request and Response?

Tags: fuzzing, zap

I'm relatively new to using OWASP ZAP. I tried fuzzing POST requests with Zap and am able to see all the messages sent in the *Fuzzer* tab.

When I select one of the messages in the *Fuzzer* tab, I can see the respective *Request and Response* in the relative tabs.

Now, I can export the *Fuzzer* results in CSV format from its tab. But, that doesn't have the respective request and response data for each test.

I checked the various report templates in "*Generate Report*", but none of them were helpful either.

I tried to look it up on the internet but wasn't able to find a solution.

Is it possible to generate a report of the Fuzzer test along with the request and response data in Zap? If yes, how can I do that? If no, Is there a simple workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to select all of the fuzzer messages in the table, right click and "Save Selected Entries as HAR (HTTP Archive File)”.
You could also write an HTTP Sender script to save them in whatever format you like.
https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/main/httpsender

Comment: Can you share a sample HTTP Semder script?

Comment: We have lots of examples on https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/main/httpsender :)